# Google Fusion Table KML Polyline Not Showing

Tags: kml, google-fusion-tables

I have been using a google fusion table for a project with the goal of showing two points connecting using a poly-line on a map. However I can not get the poly-line to show up on my map using the following format:

```
<LineString><coordinates>
lat,long 
lat,long 
</coordinates></LineString>
```

Can anybody help me figure out what I am doing wrong, because when I look at other examples using the same formatting they seem to work just fine.

Here is the link to my fusion table:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1dHu30w-Gcl91up6sCJeJGh0ghhdiGrh8vcmDQf_L

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that your LAT LONG is suppose to be order as LONG LAT.
For reference here is an example:

```
<LineString>
    <extrude>1</extrude>
    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
    <coordinates>
        -122.364383,37.824664,0 
        -122.364152,37.824322,0
        -122.363999,37.824202,0
        -122.363844,37.824122,0
    </coordinates>
</LineString>
```

Here is the link to the example: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#example_93